# Application Center: Installation AccessController is not working in a web browser

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I tried to grant user permission using IBM MobileFirst App Center Access Control. But it doesn't work on web browser. All apps show on browser. Do you know how to use this feature/how to fix this issue?

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific. What did you change? How did you grant the permission? Have you used the documentation on installing and configuring the App Center? https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/c_configuration_of_the_applicati.html

Comment: @Nguyen, can you reply to the above?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I mean that I want to apply application downloading permission for each group user. Example: user A can see and download app A, other user cannot see it. It work on IBM Appcenter native app but when I open installers.html in device browser using user B, I see all other apps. maybe the user restrict doesn't work on browser or I miss config something?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to install apps:

1. the installers.html page: this is normally only used to install the Application Center Client itself
2. through the Application Center Client, once it is installed on the device

Nguyen is correct, the installers.html page does not respect access control while the Application Center Client does. The reason is that the installers.html is not designed for a large list of apps, it shows only those apps explicitely marked as installer, and typically should only contain the App Center Client itself. The access control that defines who is allowed to install which app should however work fine in the Application Center client.